# Argument of BufferedReader() constructor is an object of an abstract class

Tags: java, bufferedreader, reader

Consider the following code snippet.

```
BuffereReader br = new BufferedReader(Reader in);
```

In this case, the argument of the `BufferedReader()` constructor is an object of an abstract class called `Reader`. We know that abstract classes cannot be instantiated in Java. Then, how the object `in` of the `Reader` class got instantiated in this case?

Comment: The object is not a `Reader` but any class which implements a `Reader`

Answer (score 0):

The `BufferedReader` constructors receive a reference to an instance of type `Reader`. Since `Reader` is an abstract class, this means the constructors can only receive references to instances of concrete sub-classes of the `Reader` class.

Comment: Can we use subclass instances such as ( FileReader  Or InputStreamReader ) instead of the parent class instances (Reader in)?